# SQL Server 2008 Merge Statement Multiple Match Conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, merge

I am attempting to bring in claim data in an incremental manner. I am matching source and target on `System` (`varchar`) and `ClaimNum` (`varchar`), with a hash of the other columns to check for changes.

I have my merge statement (simplified):

```
MERGE target
USING source ON target.System = source.System
             AND target.ClaimNum = source.ClaimNum

WHEN MATCHED AND target.HashValue <> source.HashValue
THEN {update claim record data}

WHEN MATCHED AND target.HashValue = source.HashValue
THEN {update claim record as "checked"}

WHEN NOT MATCHED
THEN {insert new claim record}
```

However, I can't have 2 matched conditions. How else can I accomplish this with a merge statement?

This is being used on SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `CASE` or `IIF`(SQL Server 2012) to add custom logic:

```
MERGE target
USING source
  ON target.System = source.System
 AND target.ClaimNum = source.ClaimNum
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
   UPDATE SET column_name = 
            CASE WHEN target.HashValue = source.HashValue THEN ...
                 ELSE ...
            END
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN {insert new claim record}
```

**EDIT:**

If it is only `UPDATE` you could use multiple conditions/set to the same value to skip:

```
...
UPDATE SET column_name1 = 
            CASE WHEN condition1 THEN ...
                 ELSE column_name1
            END
           ,column_name2 = 
             CASE WHEN condition1 THEN ...
                  WHEN condition2 THEN ...
                  ELSE column_name2
             END
           ,...
```

---

Note:

If source/target `HashValue` is nullable you should handle it using `COALESCE/ISNULL/adding OR target.HashValue IS NULL...`. Comparison operators don't work with `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks for your response; however, I have multiple columns that are affected by the match statement.  For example, I need to have like a case statement for the match condition, ya know?

Comment: @wk4997 Then you use multiple case statements, and if you don't want to update them just set to same value `col_name = CASE WHEN condition THEN ... ELSE col_name END` plus you could have different conditions for each column